# By using FormData to upload multiple files along with other form values in spring mvc MultiPartHttpServlet Request object return only one file

Tags: jquery, spring

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file1",file1.files[0]);
formData.append("file1",file2.files[0]);
formData.append("file1",file3.files[0]);
formData.append("file1",file4.files[0]);
```

On controller I am getting only one file.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the files with the same name `file1` everytime, so at the end you end up with just one file. You need to assign a unique name to each file.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file1",file1.files[0]);
formData.append("file2",file2.files[0]);
formData.append("file3",file3.files[0]);
formData.append("file4",file4.files[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!! But I am appending with diffrent name like file1,file2,file3 and file4.